# How to get attributes from a dynamic element?

Tags: jquery

I have this dynamic element:

```
<ul>
    <li class="image1" data-sub="foo 1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="image2" data-sub="foo 2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to get `class`, `data-sub` and `<img>` from this code.

js:

```
$('body').on('click', 'li', function(i){
    rel = i.currentTarget.className;
    img = i.currentTarget.innerHTML;
    sub = $(this).attr('data-sub');

    console.log(rel, img, sub);
});
```

The `class` and `<img>` are returning, but `data-sub` is returning undefined.
I also tried `console.log( this.attr('data-sub') )` but it's not working.

When I use `console.log(i)`, it returns me the object, that's why I'm using `i.currentTarget`, but custom data attribute doesn't seem to be created there.

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Can't repro / works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltft3d2n/

Comment: @FelixKling it working because these elements aren't dynamic. Try insert them via js

Comment: Still works: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltft3d2n/2/

Comment: Instead of using .attr("data-sub") try .data("sub"). Ran into a few inconsistencies across browsers in the past.

Comment: Please provide your own http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which reproduces the problem. We can't really help you if we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Why did you accept myfunkyside's answer? What was the issue? I'm asking because I can't reproduce the problem with your code, so I believe other visitors trying to identify whether they have the same problem with have a hard time to understand why the accepted answer solved your described issue.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't know why that code wasn't working for me. His answer worked fine. You put -1 to my question just because of that? Grow up.

Comment: Sorry if you feel offended by my downvote. I downvoted because, given the information in your question, the problem can't be reproduced. While I'm happy that you solved your problem, I have future visitors in mind. Right now, you described a problem A, posted working(!) code B and accepted a (subpar) answer with code C. The "bad" part is that code C even violates some of the premises of your problem, namely the dynamic addition of the elements (what you complained about in my first jsFiddle example btw, which also "works fine") and it doesn't explain what was changed and why...

Comment: ... I just want future visitors to understand that the code you posted doesn't expose the problem you mentioned and that they should not blindly replace their code with the one in the accepted answer.

Comment: @FelixKling I see. When I finish this job I'm working on, I'll look for what I was doing wrong and I'll post here and let you know

Comment: Thanks! FWIW (looking at the question title), whether an element existed from the very beginning (i.e. was parsed from the HTML source) or created dynamically at runtime doesn't make a difference. You can get the attribute in the exact same way in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead (HTML is the same):

```
$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var rel = $(this).attr('class');
    var img = $(this).html();
    var sub = $(this).data('sub'); //CREDIT TO jrummell

    console.log(rel, img, sub);
});
```

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edbdohf3/2/**

- I removed the `i` and `i.currentTarget`. You can just use `$(this)` everywhere to reference the clicked `li`. (I translated `.className` and `.innerHTML` into jQuery accordingly.)
- I changed `.attr('data-sub')` to `.data('sub')` (credit to jrummell). The first seems to work too, but the latter is apparently the better way to go.
- I added `var` before each of the variables in the function. If you only need those variables inside the function, use `var`, otherwise you will unnecessarily create global variables. If you also need the variables outside of the function, you obviously *do need* global variables, in which case you should not add `var` before the variables inside the function. (But here I can't see whether you already declared those variables earlier in your script.)

---

***If this still doesn't work***, try changing

`$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {`
to
`$('li').on('click', function() {`

This links the `li` elements directly, instead of delegating through `body`. This ensures that `$(this)` unquestionably references the clicked `li` element.
In theory there shouldn't be any difference, but it can never hurt to try..

Comment: The OP has problems retrieving the `data-sub` attribute and you are telling him keep doing the same thing but change other, unrelated code?

Comment: yep:) since `$(this)` now unquestionably references the `li` element

Comment: Ah, I missed that you also changed the way you bound the event handler. However, 1) The OP said he has *dynamic elements*, so he probably can't do that and has no other choice than using event delegation. 2) jQuery ensures that `this` refers to the element that matches the selector passed to `.on` when using event delegation. So, even with the OPs code, `$(this)` will also "unquestionably references to the `li` element". An in general, instead of just posting, please explain the problem with the OP's code and how your solutions solve it.